# Replace string in all files containing certain text but on certain line only

Tags: c#, file-io, full-text-search, replace

I need to get all *.config files in a directory and its sub-directories containing the string MySettings.xru.

In all those files that are found, on only the line containing the string MySettings.xru I need to replace the text db001 with db002.

So, for example, if I have:

```
RandomSettings.xru someOtherWords Database=db001 blah, blah, blah...
MySettings.xru Lalala Database=db001 blah, blah, blah...
YourSettings.xru Hey yo Database=db001 blah, blah, blah...
```

The results should be:

```
RandomSettings.xru someOtherWords Database=db001 blah, blah, blah...
MySettings.xru Lalala Database=db002 blah, blah, blah...
YourSettings.xru Hey yo Database=db001 blah, blah, blah...
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: Solved it myself.

Comment: Find files (recursive directory search), process each file, read each line, check for match, String.Replace if matched, write line to temp file, close the open file, rename (Move) temp file to overwrite the original.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your problem? Do you not know what overall method to use? Do you not know how to do the file access? Do you not know how to modify a file? Do you not know how to find the line you need to change... This question covers a lot of ground at the moment and would be easiest if you provided more of an idea of which bits you are comfortable with and which bits you need help with... Preferably with code you've tried. :)

Comment: Consider this comment as a tip only : If you have visual studio ,you can include the folders in the solution and use the search and replace feature of visual studio .Best of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\", "*.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

int counter = 0;
string currentFile = string.Empty;
string currentLine = string.Empty;
string updatedLine = string.Empty;

foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    currentFile = File.ReadAllText(file);

    if (currentFile.Contains("MySettings.xru"))
    {
        counter++;
        Debug.Print("Found in " + file);

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine();

                if (currentLine.Contains("MySettings.xru"))
                {
                    updatedLine = currentLine.Replace("db001", "db002");

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        currentFile = currentFile.Replace(currentLine, updatedLine);

        // If file is ReadOnly then remove that attribute.
        FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(file);
        if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            File.SetAttributes(file, attributes ^ FileAttributes.ReadOnly);

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(currentFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer above ;

> string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\", *.config",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Specifying search Pattern and Search Option didn't work for me (for what ever reason). However simply mentioning search directory could also do the trick.

> string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(searchDirectory);

Answer (score 0):

Consider this comment as a tip only : If you have visual studio ,you can include the folders in the solution and use the search and replace feature of visual studio .Best of luck